# Javac compiler bug with class name antbuild

Tags: java, ant, javac

I was trying to do an ant build that compiled a java project source code when i ran into a problem i could not explain. First my ant target:

```
<target name="compile-companymanage" depends="compile-company">
    <mkdir dir="${companymanagebin}"/>
    <javac destdir="${companymanagebin}">
        <src path="${companymanagesrc}" />
        <classpath refid="companyManage.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

After running that i get the error:

```
[javac] project\src\com\company\manage\vo\InvoiceL‌ineSupplierVM.java:31: error: class InvoiceLineSupplierVM is public, should be declared in a file named InvoiceLineSupplierVM.java
[javac] public class InvoiceL‌ineSupplierVM
[javac]        ^
[javac] 1 error
```

We have tried it with different projects and they compile just fine. Hope someone can help me.

We have tried renaming the file and class with the same name.

Comment: Could you check to see if you have any non printable characters in this particular class or file name?

Comment: This can compile via eclipse so i do not know what to say @npinti

Comment: I did not propose to check the names because of the extra space, I assumed that you copied that from somewhere and the formatting carried over. Just for completeness you could, does `InvoiceL‌ineSupplierVM.java:31` contain the deceleration of the class? Also, for completeness sake, could you try and rename the class and its file? So you would type in the same name again? This way, any hidden characters *should* be removed.

Comment: The reason behind that is i had a fight with the stack overflow formatter @Ascalonian

Comment: what happens in lines 1-30? only imports, or do you have another `public class...` part there?

Comment: No classes there @Steffen

Comment: @npinti
Looks like it was some strange charecter nonsense
Renamed it to IS.java worked
Renamed it via copy pasta to old name.java : didnt work
Renamed it to another random name: worked
Renamed it to old name via retyping: worked 
Answer my question and ill accept it

Comment: @Florenze: I have added an answer to fit with this Site's Q/A format. If you think I should add something else, please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the answer for completeness sake and to simplify the lives of other people which will encounter this error in the future.

Most likely you have a non-printable character in one of your names, either your class name or your file name. This will cause a mismatch between what the compiler has or expects.

To solve this problem, what one usually does is to rename the files and classes involved. It is important that when renaming, you do not copy and paste the name but rather type it in. This will make sure that non-printable characters do not end up in the names of the file and class as happened.